# How can I limit selected columns from an eloquent relationship?

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, laravel-5

I have a concept of 3 items all stored in a database with relationships defined between them all.  The items reflect answers to a survey.  The tables are:

results: id, enrolment_id, assessment_id, completed (int), timestamps
result_answers: id, result_id, answer_id, timestamps
answers: id, answer_plain, answer_html, timestamps

I am trying to build an object that contains the following:

```
Results (array){
  id, enrolment_id, assessment_id, created_at
  Result_answers (array){
    Answer{
      id,answer_plain
    }
  }
}
```

I am using the following code:

```
$result = Result::where('enrolment_id', '=', $id)
    ->where('completed', '=', 1)
    ->with(['result_answers' => function($query) {
        $query->with(['answer' => function($query) {
            $query->select('id', 'answer_plain');
        }]);
    }])
    ->select(['id', 'enrolment_id', 'created_at'])
    ->get();
return response()->json($result);
```

Unfortunately, this is giving me a lot of fields that aren't required, effectively outputting every field in every table in each of the relationships.  How can I limit what is being outputted?  It seems to be mainly a problem with `result_answers` as I don't need any data from that table outputting, just the relationship to `answer` (which is working).

I have tried supplied an empty `->select()` to that `with()` but with no luck.

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

With Many-to-Many relationship between **Result** and **Answer** you shouldn't really care about the intermediate **result_answers** table. You shouldn't define a relation in your models to **results_answers** table either.

All the work related to loading the data should be done by Eloquent, provided you have your relations defined correctly.

Your models should contain the following relations:

```
class Result extends Model {
  public function answers() {
    return $this->belongsToMany(Answer::class, 'results_answers');
  }
}
```

With that defined, you should be able to get answers for results in a much simpler manner:

```
$results = Result::where('enrolment_id', '=', $id)
  ->where('completed', '=', 1)
  ->with(['answers' => function($query) {
        $query->select('id', 'answer_plain');
  }])
  ->select(['id', 'enrolment_id', 'created_at'])
 ->get();
```

Now you should be able to iterate through the results and related answers with:

```
foreach ($results as $result) {
  foreach ($result->answers as $answer) {
    var_dump($answer);
  }
}
```

You can also replace:

```
return response()->json($results);
```

with
    return $results;

as all jsonable content returned from a controller will be automatically serialized to JSON before it's returned to the browser.

Answer (score 0):

You may pass all the fields you want in `get()` as an array keys function like this:

```
$results = Result::where('enrolment_id', '=', $id)
->where('completed', '=', 1)`
  ->with(['answers' => function($query) {
    $query->get(['id', 'answer_plain']);
  }])->get(['id', 'enrolment_id', 'created_at'])
```